# Building a notification using Timer()

Tags: android

I want to create a notification in my application that warns me everytime there's an UPDATE or a new entry in my SQL Server database.
i used Timer() and i compared the new data with the old data, but the problem is that it only notify me when i log in and it sends the notification continuously.
i want to be warned even if i'm not in the app.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String user = "", pass = "";
                Bundle b = ActivityTwo.this.getIntent().getExtras();
                if (b != null) {
                    user = b.getString("user");
                    pass = b.getString("pass");
                }
                String q12 = "Select TOP(6) readingdate,hp07,hp10 from Workers,TLD where card=cardID AND username='" + user + "' AND password='" + pass + "' order by readingdate desc ";
                try {
                    connect = ConnectionHelper(username, password, db, ipaddress);
                    if (connect == null) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityTwo.this).setTitle("Error Message")
                                .setMessage("Error in connection!!")
                                .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    }
                                }).show();
                    } else {
                        s12 = connect.prepareStatement(q12);
                        r12 = s12.executeQuery();
                        int[] ka = new int[6];
                        int c = 0;
                        while (r12.next()) {
                            String h07 = r12.getString("hp07");
                            String h10 = r12.getString("hp10");
                            int l07 = Integer.valueOf(h07);
                            ka[c] = l07;
                            c++;
                            //Toast.makeText(ActivityTwo.this, hp071 + " " + h07 + " " + hp101 + " " + h10, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                                if (ka[i]!=hp071[i]) {
                                    final Intent emptyIntent = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ActivityTwo.this, 0, emptyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                                    android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                                            (android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder) new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(ActivityTwo.this)
                                                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                                                    .setContentText("NEW UPDATE")
                                                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                                    mBuilder.setTicker("this is the notif");
                                    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                                    mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                                    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
                                    Notification not = mBuilder.build();
                                    not.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                                    not.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

                                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                    notificationManager.notify(1, not);
                                    hp071[i]=ka[i];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}, 0);
```

so where is my mistake?? the app is not that complicated to use the google cloud messaging, just a simple warning.

Comment: use firebase for notifications when your data is coming from online server

Comment: ok but, how should i know when to send? @jagapathi

Comment: trigger firebase when you insert data